# Isolating an attribute in bs4/beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to isolate a value which is listed as an attribute through the use of beautiful soup (bs4). I've listed my output but I'm not sure how to get just the string from "value" in a string form.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """
<div class="buttons">
    <form method="POST" action="/1/token/approve">
        <a class="button primary" href="/login?returnUrl=%2F1%2Fauthorize%3FrequestKey%3Df079a57f7157bf084676c5a9c3d0443e">Log in</a>
        <input type="submit" class="deny" value="Deny">

        <input type="hidden" name="requestKey" value="f079a57f7157bf084676c5a9c3d0443e">

        <!-- Need to pull this value -->
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="1500374930141/76d6e6bf4e95732eece754cc00315a242db0ffcf2758052c1fd64f2e6024611b">

    </form>
</div>
"""

#pull web page
f = requests.get(html)

# pass HTML to soup
soup = bs(f.text, "lxml")
bsIn = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':'signature'})

print (bsIn) # returns <input name="signature" type="hidden" value="1500387161323/9a240ffc8dfff875bc272f0defba27e58f4ffd8e7a29d00edc3528776bca3039"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain HTML/XML attributes in beautiful soup through **indexing**, like:

```
print(bsIn['value'])
```

This will thus print the string:

```
'1500387161323/9a240ffc8dfff875bc272f0defba27e58f4ffd8e7a29d00edc3528776bca3039'
```

It will be printed like:

```
1500387161323/9a240ffc8dfff875bc272f0defba27e58f4ffd8e7a29d00edc3528776bca3039
```